# MongoDb connection refused

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

This is my first attempt to consume MongoDB. I've got Mongo running:

```
ps -ef | grep [m]ongo
mongodb  11023  1  0 Jun24 ? 00:00:03 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

And the error comes as the result of doing

```
Datastore.save( stuff );  // (pseudo code)
```

The error:

> ```
> Jun 27, 2011 3:20:29 PM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector fetchMaxBsonObjectSize
> WARNING: Exception determining maxBSON size using0
> java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [russ-elite-book/127.0.1.1:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>     at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:206)
>     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:94)
>     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:75)
>     at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:129)
>     at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:138)
>     ...
> ```

Note that I'm using *127.0.0.1:27017* for my connection, which works to the Mongo shell. Also, I get the admin page in the browser using *`http://localhost:28017`*.

Profuse thanks for any and all ideas!

Comment: I had this happen when I forgot to specify the env var with the connection string. so it defaults to localhost but I didn't have anything running on localhost...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I think it slightly bad form to answer one's own question, but in fact, the answer turns out to be none of those suggested. Nevertheless, my profuse thanks to all of them. When answering a question, one needs to be able to assume it's based on correctly installed and working software. I did not have that.)

I installed MongoDB using the Ubuntu Software Center. It worked from the shell and from the browser as noted elsewhere in this question. However, it did not work from Java (nor from Django either).

The problem, despite what it said in the Java stack trace, was simply "connection refused."

**The solution is to install it from proper Mongo sources and not to trust the Ubuntu repository.**

(Yes, this also frequently happens to other products obtain from there too, like Eclipse, but you know it's such a nice service that you want to trust it.)

If you want to read how I installed what then worked, check out http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/mongodb.html.

Comment: mongo maintainers always make proper packages to sid. your conclusion is funny =)

Comment: Funny as it might be, the exact same issue has just happened to me on Ubuntu 12.04. I installed the mongodb package from the official Ubuntu repo and I couldn't access it from Java. I removed the package and installed the from the 10gen repository. It worked fine from the Java driver.

Comment: @Rodrigue: This is bs. The difference is the config file. Ubuntu/Mongodb simply doesn't realize that localhost = 127.0.0.1, and when you have 127.0.0.1 in the config file and connect with localhost, then it doesn't work, because you don't connect to a bound IP. The 10gen has a different config file where the line in question is either commented out or not present. This is worse, not better, as you can connect from non-localhost computers (e.g. the internet).

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue because I upgraded my mongo using brew. To fix this issue. Look for the conf file(which might not be located in the bin directory where you start your mongodb from)

/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-2.2.whatever/mongod.conf, and comment out the "bind_ip" property.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 (and probably earlier versions too) the configuration file is `/etc/mongod.conf`. Commenting out the `bind_ip` option allowed me to access MongoDB from a different host.

Comment: Commenting out the bind_ip on a fresh installation worked for me, thanks

Comment: Or just use 127.0.0.1 in the connectionstring, instead of localhost (proper security measure).

Comment: 127.0.0.1 seemed to work instead of localhost on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 8):

Most likely the Java driver cannot connect to the address specified.
Make sure that you can connect to that address `127.0.1.1:27017` using the shell and run "`db.isMaster()`".
Maybe it is an issue of `127.0.1.1` vs `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I'm using 127.0.0.1:27017. When I run the mongo shell on that address, it comes up, but typing db.isMaster() produces: Tue Jun 28 08:41:45 JS Error: TypeError: db.isMaster is not a function (shell):0

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but my solution was different.  I was using "localhost" as the host name and changing it to "127.0.0.1" fixed it.

Comment: Thankyou! I am using studio3T to connect.By default the server configuration had localhost but changing it 127.0.0.1 solved it.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that it is [an issue with the Java MongDB driver](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-249).

There are two solutions:

1. Using [version 2.8](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads) or higher of the Java driver.
2. Edit the configuration files and if it contains the line `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` or `bind_ip = localhost`, comment it out.

#### Eating humble pie...

As I showed in my comment to [Russ Bateman's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511920/191191), it seemed like an issue with the Ubuntu package at first. The real reason is that the config file that comes with it does define a value for `bind_ip`...

Comment: i had same error when i was tring to connect mongoDB on a server(not my pc), and commenting bind_ip fixed my problem ;)

Comment: What if it has bind_ip = 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue because I installed my mongo using apt-get. Here's how to fix it:

1. Find your mongod.conf file. In Ubuntu 14.04, it's /etc/mongod.conf
2. Open mongod.conf file and command the line bindIp = 127.0.0.1
3. Restart mongod

Comment: U mean comment?

Comment: can you please explain what bindIp address is?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is a security issue or an invalid url.  If you used the default configuration, you should be able to access the http://yourmachine:28017.  See if you can navigate to the admin page from this url.  If you are able to navigate to the admin url, just replace the port number with 27017 in your app.  It should work.

Comment: Thank you, http://localhost:28017 works fine. And I'm certain I'm using 27017 in my application too.

Comment: I found this answer here.  It might help you. http://serverfault.com/questions/154078/unable-to-connect-to-a-remote-database/154113#154113

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without seeing your .conf file contents. One thing I would recommend is running the mongo shell and seeing if you can connect, query, and write from it.  This will help isolate server vs. a java client issue. Additionally it may give you a different form of the error which may be a hint.

Are you setting --port in your .conf file?

Comment: Yes, I can connect using the mongo shell and have on purpose changed nothing for the moment in any configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a completely different solution. I am using Spring MVC framework, and all I had to do is to confirm that the configuration XML files are saying the same thing in the /target folder as well as the non-target folders.  Once that was adjusted, everything worked.  The problem was that everything worked when run from a STS, but when deployed, I had the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using pymongo connecting to mongo atlas cluster. There is a connection limit and I suspected I opened too many connections so rewriting the code to share one connection and properly closing it solved the problem.