# com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBPort.findOne failed

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongointernalexception

I am trying to adopt [that](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial.html) example into my existing Spring application. However I get that error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBPort.findOne failed
```

I get admin panel with that URL:

```
http://localhost:28017/
```

so should I use 28017 or 27017 as port number at my configuration file. I tried to use 2.2 instead of 2.4 as Java connecter but I get different error:

```
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort error
SEVERE: MyPort.error called
java.io.EOFException
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:32)
    ...
```

Second error may be related to joda when I searched about it but I don't know how to solve it.

Any ideas about solving problem?

**PS1:**

I use that at my configuration file:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg value="userMongoDb"/>
    <constructor-arg value="mycollection"/>
</bean>
```

However at the line:

```
<constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
```

It says that:

```
can no resolve bean mongo
```

at my Intellij IDEA. Why it does that I didn't understand because everything seems OK.

**PS2:**

I use Ubuntu 11.4 on a 64 bit server. First error maybe related to my OS.

**PS3:**

When I use 2.5.2 as mongo java driver I get that error:

```
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector fetchMaxBsonObjectSize
WARNING: null
java.io.EOFException
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:37)
        ...
```

**PS4:**

[There is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499268/mongodb-connection-refused) and I will check if error is related to Ubuntu Software Center or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 27017 as port to connect. Also that question's answer is important: [MongoDb connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499268/mongodb-connection-refused) I installed my Mongo DB not from Ubuntu Update Center and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port 27017, now it is working. I used ubuntu MongoDb.