# Celerybeat with Mongo Connection Error

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, celeryd, celerybeat

I'm trying to set up a celery task queue with celerybeat for periodic updates on a database. My celeryd service seems to working perfectly but celerybeat keeps giving me a `Connection error: [Errno 111]`:

```
[2012-09-10 09:40:18,954: INFO/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Starting...
[2012-09-10 09:40:19,001: ERROR/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 2.0 seconds...
[2012-09-10 09:40:22,004: ERROR/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 4.0 seconds...
[2012-09-10 09:40:32,012: ERROR/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 6.0 seconds...
[2012-09-10 09:40:53,030: ERROR/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 8.0 seconds...
[2012-09-10 09:41:29,052: ERROR/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 10.0 seconds...
```

Here's my celeryconfig file:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
import datetime

BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/tasks'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'mongodb'
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "celery",
    "taskmeta_collection": "celery_taskmeta",
}

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update-linked-calendars': {
        'task': 'tasks.initiateUpdate',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/1')
    },
}

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('tasks',)
```

I've been working on this for a long time and am still confused as to why I am getting this error. I don't have a user/password for my MongoDB (using it perfectly for my application). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just to confirm the `mongod` is up and running on localhost.  What does `mongo` give you from that box?

Comment: try this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499268/mongodb-connection-refused

Comment: @andrean my mongo installation is from the 10gen repo.

Comment: @Ross mongod is working perfectly...i can connect to the mongo shell and is is working perfectly for my other applications. the problem seems to be with just celery.

Comment: the link to the answer mentioned that the issue may be fixed by:
"Edit the configuration files and if it contains the line bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 or bind_ip = localhost, comment it out."