# Unable to create a DB using mongoose even with mongod running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongod running in one tab, mongo shell works perfectly in another.

Here is my code, I have mongoose version 5.9.10 installed in my project folder using npm and mongodb 3.5.6

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27071/fruitsDB", { useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify:false, useCreateIndex:true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
const fruit = new Fruit ({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 8,
    review: "gud"
});

fruit.save();
```

run, get a bunch of errors and warnings and no db is created according to mongo shell

Here is what the error I'm getting when I do node app.js in hyper

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27071
at new MongooseServerSelectionError (C:\Users\ahuja\Desktop\code\Web Development\fruitsProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)      
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\ahuja\Desktop\code\Web Development\fruitsProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\ahuja\Desktop\code\Web Development\fruitsProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ahuja\Desktop\code\Web Development\fruitsProj\app.js:3:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
(node:7980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: This is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning so all you need to do is check the connection code in try catch block to handle any error if occurred. Please try this.

Comment: @Nayan I'm pretty new to this stuff, it'll be a great help if you guide me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/fruitsDB", { useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify:false, useCreateIndex:true })
  .then(() => {
    log.info("successfully connected to db");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    log.error("db connection failed " + err);
  });
```

Comment: Returns me this, even tho I have mongod running on port 27071, mongo shell's working too
"db connection failed MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27071"

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499268/mongodb-connection-refused)

Comment: I found a solution on youtube, basically I have to write just localhost in the link and not localhost:27071